# Finding Nonzero Minimum in an Array where index 0 is 0 C++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, minimum

I am working on a project for my computer science class, but it requires me to find the minimum in a 2d array row, then return the index of the column, then next search the row with that column index. I am currently trying to get it to correctly find all the mins. The function I have now finds the right min for all rows except the first row which starts with a zero. Here is the Function:

```
int ComputeLowestPheromone(int matrix[][SIZE], int visitedColns[], int currRow)
{
    int row_min[SIZE];
    for(int i = currRow; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        row_min[i] = matrix[i][0];
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j] == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(row_min[i] > matrix[i][j])
            {
                row_min[i] = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        cout  << "Row Min " << i << ": " << row_min[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

The Current output: [CurrentOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKFsC.png)

So my question is, **why is it correctly ignoring zero for all rows except the first?** And once I have that solved, a tip on how to save that current index correctly would be awesome.

Comment: 1) Please provide [mre]. 2) Please copy-paste text, instead of providing pictures of it (I am talking about the picture of your output).

Comment: The `visitedColns` parameters is not used in your function. Can you provide an example how your function should be called? You can return your current index (by the way your function does not return anything but has integer return type).

Answer (score 2):

Change your initialization from

```
row_min[i] = matrix[i][0];
```

to

```
row_min[i] = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

Answer (score 1):

This assignment of row_min is causing the issue:

```
row_min[i] = matrix[i][0];
```

You are initializing this to presumably a zero value.

```
if(row_min[i] > matrix[i][j])
{
    row_min[i] = matrix[i][j];
}
```

Although you are normally using continue to avoid 0 assignment you have already assigned the value to 0 and this if statement will not run.
Initialize row_min to `row_min[i] = 0xffffffff` or `std::numeric_limits<int>::max();`
0xffffffff is assuming 32bit int.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that is what I was accutally assuming, I just didn't know about std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); after reading up about it on cppreference, I understand it. Thanks for the tip.